# How do i limit certain paths on my webpage limited to admin ? [React, Firebase for auth]

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a web app for students management. In that same app there is a section "path/admin". I want to know how do i limit access to that page only to couple of users.

My idea is that i take out uid of the user and store it in the code (sounds unsafe). While login i check it with .... ''if(currentUser.uid === storedAdminUid) {path/admin} else {path/student}".

i am skeptical about it cause i heard that you shouldn't store auth related code in the frontEnd. HELPPPP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way how you can achieve that, I particularly like the one proposed by [Robin Wieruch](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial) in his amazing article about using React with Firebase. But here the bits related to your question:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import * as ROUTES from "../../constants/routes";
import { FirebaseContext } from "../../firebase";
import useAuthUser from "./useAuthUser";

const withAuthorization = condition => Component => {
  function WithAuthorization(props) {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const user = useAuthUser();
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
      const releaseAuthListener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(
        authUser => {
          if (!condition(authUser)) {
            history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
          }
        },
        () => {
          history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
        }
      );

      return () => releaseAuthListener();
    }, []);

    return condition(user) && <Component {...props} />;
  }

  return WithAuthorization;
};

export default withAuthorization;
```

Here we have `withAuthorization` HOC which basically wraps component in a condition to access that component.

Here how we can use it:

```
function AccountPage() {
    const authUser = useAuthUser();

    if(!authUser) return <h1>User Unknown</h1>

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Account: {authUser.email}</h1>
            {/* <PasswordForgetForm />
            <PasswordChangeForm /> */}
        </div>
    )
}

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(condition)(AccountPage);
```

Here we check that user should be just authenticated in order to access that page.

```
function AdminPage() {
   // ... IMPLEMENTATION
}    

const condition = authUser => authUser && !!authUser.roles[ROLES.ADMIN];
    
export default withAuthorization(condition)(AdminPage);
```

Here we allow access not only when user is authenticated but also when user is authorized because that user has a role set for him/her.

Please take a look on this [repository](https://github.com/PompolutZ/react-firebase-auth-skeleton) where you can see everything in the context. And read the original Robin's article.

Also I guess you can simplify even more, to just use hooks, without writing HOC.